# How to set Axios headers to a instance (not globally)

Tags: reactjs, google-api, axios, request-headers

I'm trying to send a get request to Google Books Api with axios.
It works if the Authorization headers is not set.
However after I log in to my app and set the Authorization headers to a token, Google Api responds with.

```
errors:[{domain: "global", reason: "authError", message: "Invalid Credentials", locationType: "header",…}]
message:"Invalid Credentials"
```

Sorry I'm still quite new to programming and I'd just like to know the best way to bypass that error. I tried setting the Authorization header to it's own instance instead of setting it globally but could not find a way to do that in the action call in my React app.

Please help and thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You can try like this

//Set the header

```
var header = {
               'Content-Type': 'application/json',
               'Authorization':'Bearer '.concat(USER_TOKEN)
            }

axios.get(URL, header)
 .then(response => {
     console.log(JSON.stringify(response));
  })
 .catch((error) => {
     console.log('error ' + error);
  });
```

Answer (score 2):

Thank you guys for your help! They didn't work for me because of the way I set up my jwt on the client side.

The code below ended up working for me because I just needed to override the global Authorization header.

```
import axios from 'axios';
const axiosInstance = axios.create({
  baseURL: url
});

axiosInstance.defaults.headers.common = '';

export default axiosInstance;
```

Answer (score 1):

To set the authorization token in headers using axios in get request you can try the following code:

```
const AuthStr = 'Bearer '.concat(USER_TOKEN);
    axios.get(URL, { headers: { Authorization: AuthStr } }).then(response => {
            console.log(response.data);
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            console.log('error: ' + error);
          });
```